# Sufficient conditions for $E(G\eta|Z=1)\geq 0$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Consider three random variables $G,Z,\eta$. $G$ and $Z$ are   binary. We assume
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(1) \quad E(\eta|Z=1)=0,\\
&(2) \quad \Pr(G=1| Z=1)=1.
\end{aligned}
$$
In turn,
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(G\eta|Z=1)& =E(G \eta|G=1, Z=1)\Pr(G=1|Z=1)= E(\eta| G=1, Z=1).
\end{aligned}
$$
Further, observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(\eta|Z=1)&=E( \eta|G=1, Z=1)\Pr(G=1|Z=1)+E(\eta|G=0, Z=1)\Pr(G=0|Z=1)=E( \eta|G=1, Z=1).
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore,
$$
(3) \quad E(G\eta|Z=1)=0.
$$

**Question**: Instead of (3), I'd like to write down some sufficient conditions to get the weaker conclusion
$$
(3') \quad E(G\eta|Z=1)\geq 0.
$$
To this end, I would like to replace (2) with "some" inequality condition, such as
$$
\begin{aligned}
& E(\eta| Z=1, G=1)\geq E(\eta| Z=1, G=0)\\
& \Pr(G=1|Z=1)\geq \Pr(G=0|Z=1)\\
& \Pr(G=1|Z=1)\geq \Pr(G=1)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
or similar. I can keep (1). Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am weak in random variables and below is handwaving.

Since the given and the required conditions concerns case $Z=1$, we restrict our consideration to this case. Then Condition (1) becames $E(\eta)=0$ and we need to have $E(G\eta)\ge 0$. But
$$E(G\eta)=E(G\eta|G=1)\Pr(G=1)+E(G\eta|G=0)\Pr(G=0)=E(\eta|G=1)\Pr(G=1).$$ So we need to have $E(\eta|G=1)\ge 0$ or $\Pr(G=1)=0$.

But we have $$0=E(\eta)=E(\eta|G=1)\Pr(G=1)+E(\eta|G=0)\Pr(G=0).$$

Thus if the required conclusion fails then $E(\eta|G=1)<0$ and $\Pr(G=1)>0$,
and so $E(\eta|G=0)>0$ and $\Pr(G=0)>0$. Thus the proposed condition
$E(\eta|G=1)\geq E(\eta| G=0)$ provides the required conclusion.

The other proposed conditions do not provide the required conclusion. Indeed, $\Pr(G=1|Z=1)=\Pr(G=1)$ holds always because we are restricted to the case $Z=1$.
To ensure $\Pr(G=1)\geq \Pr(G=0)$ put $\Pr(G=1)=\Pr(G=0)=1/2$. Now put $\eta=1-2G$.